# How to avoid bundling mock modules on Webpack build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, graphql

We are trying to make our React + GraphQL project independent of any other layers in the ecosystem to improve developers experience. In line with that, we have written a thin HOC that wraps Apollo own `graphql` HOC and uses an internal environment variable to switch between network fetching and mock data. On production builds, all that mock data is, obviously, not used, even if it *is* `import`ed.

Is there any way to **avoid including modules** in Webpack's **production** bundle **that you know you are not going to need** while keeping everything else the same/not breaking the app?

Something like [dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) *could* do the trick, but that ends up chunking your build rather than omitting what you don't need/want.

**UPDATE**: The app was created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) `1.0.17` and later ejected.

Comment: Would it be possible to resolve the mock data module to an empty module in production? https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js

Comment: mock apollo client to return the data you want  to mock, locally resolve apollo to your mocked module using NODE_ENV  env var in your webpack.conf file when NODE_ENV==='production' don't provide mocks for apollo, let it follow its course. That should work

Comment: @HMR I believe that would be one straight forward solution. Any ideas on how to approach that?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I get your idea. It's similar to one of the answers given below. In this case, it's not as simple as swapping one module with another, I'm afraid.

Comment: it actually is.  in your local you replace your apollo client on production you don't.

Comment: @NicolásFantone Maybe add an alias for the mock data module in the production config: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L100 I assume the module doesn't export anything but modifies Apollo? So when that code is not loaded it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @HMR has the right thing, you might write the answer down to collect juicy bounty ;) you have to use `resolve.alias` webpack option

Comment: @whitep4nther Wanted to give the bounty to mauron85 but setting an alias seems to be a cleaner solution (one global switch instead of possibly many files having conditional import statements). I'll check tomorrow and see if anyone added an answer.

Comment: @HMR It doesn't modify Apollo (in a monkey-patching sense). It wraps its `graphql` HOC with a new one, that skips its functionality entirely given a particular env var was set. All others modules, import this wrapper instead of the Apollo one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using following dir structure.

```
api
  index.js
  apimock.js
  apirest.js
```

In index.js you switch implementation depending on NODE_ENV:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./apirest');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./apimock');
}
```

You will need to use webpack DefinePlugin to set NODE_ENV:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: `"${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'}"`,
    ENABLE_DEVTOOLS: JSON.stringify(!!process.env.ENABLE_DEVTOOLS)
  }
})
```

Build command (npm script):

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

or for mock implementation:

```
NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Webpack will only bundle single implementation depending on NODE_ENV.

In your component (saga...) you simply import api:

```
import * as api from 'api';
```

Comment: This would work. But unfortunately, it's not that simple in our scenario as the data layer is being accessed through Apollo's `graphql` HOC. You've given me something to think about, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your [webpack.config.dev.js](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L94):

```
resolve: {
  alias:{
    "react-apollo":"./mock.js"
  }
}
```

Now all modules requesting react-apollo will get the mock when you compile for dev.

I don't have apollo-client but here is an example of mocking jQuery:

Your code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
console.log($().message)
```

webpack.dev.config.js:

```
alias:{
  "jquery":"./mock.js"
}
```

mock.js:

```
const org = require('../node_modules/jquery/src/jquery');
org.fn.message = "Hello from mock";
export default org;
```